# Streaming paused while in console

Tags: command-line, firefox, pulseaudio, google-chrome, ubuntu-mate

I am running Ubuntu Mate 18.04, recently updated. When I have Spotify playing in my browser (happens either with Firefox or Google Chrome), and I switch to tty1 to work, the music plays 10 or 20 seconds then stops. It automatically starts again when I come back to tty7. It appears the OS decides it doesn't need to run anything graphical while in another tty. The problem also happens with YouTube.

Is there someway to force the OS to prioritize graphical applications while I am in another tty? The interesting thing is that this used to happen, and upgrade fixed it, then an upgrade brought the problem back.

Comment: FYI: Are you aware that *flavors* of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors), so you're asking about a release that is EOL.  (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ or a recent UWN - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuWeeklyNewsletter/Issue681#Lubuntu_18.04_LTS_End_of_Life_and_Current_Support_Statuses highlights the EOL notices for Lubuntu/Ubuntu-MATE/Kubuntu/Ubuntu-Budgie, https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/ubuntu-mate-18-04-lts-reaches-end-of-life/23966/

Comment: @guiverc we don't consider flavors to go EOL before vanilla Ubuntu - see https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19616/how-long-do-we-support-ubuntu-flavors

Comment: @Zanna I don't close-vote on *flavors*, but I'm in the Ubuntu news team, so see it as within my role to try and inform people that whilst main Ubuntu increased LTS support from 3 to 5 years (*many years ago*), Ubuntu *flavors* did not and continue with 3 years for LTS (with exceptions of course; eg. Ubuntu Studio 18.04 wasn't a LTS etc)   *it's a FYI post*

Comment: @guiverc thanks for explaining - that's fine, but the reason I commented is that the post has 4 close votes for EOL. Maybe you could restyle your FYI a bit to prevent incorrect closures?